# return NULL for whois python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

module in the used https://pypi.org/project/python-whois/ python-whois

I have a simple script to practice, and when I do whois to domains separately it does what I need, but this time I need to make a for to a list of domains.

When I execute it, it only does the whois to the last domain, the others return NULL, if no response has been obtained.

What am I doing wrong?

```py
import whois
import os


with open("dominios.txt", "r") as archivo:

    for linea in archivo.readlines():
        w = whois.whois(linea)
        registrador = 'PDR Ltd. d/b/a PublicDomainRegistry.com'
        whoiSer = 'whois.publicdomainregistry.com'

        serverWhois = w.whois_server
        serverWhois = w.whois_server
        expiracion = w.expiration_date
        creacion = w.creation_date
        dominio = w.name
        destFile = r"act.txt"
        print (str(w))
        # with open(destFile, 'a') as f:
        #     f.write(str(w)+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `whois` package that exactly corresponds with your usage, so I'm not completely certain.

But the main problem I see is that you're using `readlines()` to read the file without stripping the newline from the end of the lines.  It's possible that if your file doesn't have a newline at the end, the last one is working because there's no newline.

Try instead:

```py
...
with open("dominios.txt", "r") as archivo:

    for linea in archivo.read().splitlines():
        w = whois.whois(linea)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am using the following library https://pypi.org/project/python-whois/

python-whois

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\python_whois-0.7.3-py3.10.egg-info\whoist.py", line 36, in <module>
    w = whois.whois(linea)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\whois\__init__.py", line 44, in whois
    return WhoisEntry.load(domain, text)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\whois\parser.py", line 190, in load
    return WhoisNet(domain, text)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\whois\parser.py", line 412, in __init__
    raise PywhoisError(text)
whois.parser.PywhoisError: No match for "FACILBACKUP.NET".`

Comment: I get that error

Comment: That's just an error that the whois server you contacted didn't have info for that domain.  You should catch that exception if you want to deal with domains that don't have information.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much